# How to add colored border on cardview?

Tags: android, xml, android-cardview

I am new to Android and this is my first question here.

I am trying to add a colored vertical border at the beginning of the cardview. How can I achieve it on xml ? I tried adding it with empty textview but it is messing up the whole cardview itself. Please check the picture link posted below for example.

[image: Colored boroder on cardview]

**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:contentPadding="16dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Title" />

        <TextView
            style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Content here" />
            
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Many thanks

Comment: do you need to use a cardview here? what about just a plane linearlayout and adding an ItemDecoration to your recycler view?

Comment: I am a beginner on Android and recyclerview is bit advanced for my curent skill set. So, I am using cardview here.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

try doing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp">

    <FrameLayout
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:layout_width="4dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Title" />

        <TextView
            style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Content here" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

this removes the padding from the cardview and adds a FrameLayout with a color. You then need to fix the padding in the LinearLayout then for the other fields

**Update**

If you want to preserve the card corner radius create card_edge.xml in drawable folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <solid android:color="#F00" />
    <size android:width="10dp"/>
    <padding android:bottom="0dp" android:left="0dp" android:right="0dp" android:top="0dp"/>
    <corners android:topLeftRadius="5dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:topRightRadius="0.1dp" android:bottomRightRadius="0.1dp"/>
</shape>
```

and in the frame layout use  `android:background="@drawable/card_edge"`

Comment: @GeorgeForster updated to use a drawable background to preserve the card corners if you want to still have them

Comment: did not work for me. why 4 dp width for the frame layout?

Comment: This answer should not be marked as the correct one anymore. Correct one is the one from Aung Myo Lwin.

Answer (score 276):

Start From the material design update, it support `app:strokeColor` and also `app:strokeWidth`. [see more](https://material.io/develop/android/components/material-card-view/)

to use material design update. add following code to `build.gradle`(:app)

```
dependencies {
    // ...
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    // ...
  }
```

and Change `CardView` to `MaterialCardView`

Comment: Couldn't find strokeColor.

Comment: @PrimožKralj change `cardView` to `MaterialCardView`

Comment: app:strokeColor is private when using androidx.

Comment: change ```CardView``` to ```MaterialCardView```

Comment: `MaterialCardView`'s full name is `com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView`

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant).

Comment: Known issue in strokeWidth - https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/881

Answer (score 37):

As the accepted answer requires you to add a Frame Layout, here how you can do it with material design.

Add this if you haven't already

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```

Now change to Cardview to MaterialCardView

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
app:cardElevation="2dp"

app:strokeWidth="1dp"
app:strokeColor="@color/black">
```

Now you need to change the activity theme to Theme.Material. If you are using Theme.Appcompact I will suggest you to move to Theme.Material for future projects for having better material design in you app.

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
```

Comment: this solution make black border on all card, not only left as requested

Comment: @Dracarys dear change the stroke color as required...

Answer (score 18):

I think this solution may not be efficient but it serves the purpose and adds flexibility with the border width.

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="40dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/some_color"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
    card_view:contentPadding="5dp"> <!-- Change it to customize the border width -->

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
        card_view:contentPadding="5dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

         <!-- Add your UI elements -->

        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: This is a bad solution. You are adding the view hierarchy level, which would have performance penalty.

Comment: Good idea there should be available inner features

Comment: this isn't the most performant however I haven't had a massive hit using this

Answer (score 13):

`CardView` extends FrameLayout, so it support `foreground` attribute. Using `foreground` attribute can also add border easily.

layout as follows:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/link_card"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:foreground="@drawable/bg_roundrect_ripple_light_border"
    app:cardCornerRadius="23dp"
    app:cardElevation="0dp">
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

bg_roundrect_ripple_light_border.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/ripple_color_light">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
                android:width="0.5dp"
                android:color="#DDDDDD" />
            <corners android:radius="23dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="23dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/background" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</ripple>
```

Answer (score 9):

my solution:

create a file **card_view_border.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="@color/white_background"/>
<stroke android:width="2dp" 
    android:color="@color/red" />
<corners android:radius="20dip"/>
</shape>
```

and set programmatically

```
cardView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.card_view_border);
```

Comment: This nicer because it can accomodate corner rounding if it's been applied to the cardview

Comment: Tks bro! This way can apply directly for the others like background for Linear/Relative/Constraint Layout, no need to put layout inside cardView :v

Answer (score 5):

I would like to improve the solution proposed by Amit. I'm utilizing the given resources without adding additional `shapes` or `Views`. I'm giving `CardView` a background color and then nested layout, white color to overprint yet with some `leftMargin`...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/some_color"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp">


    <!-- The left margin decides the width of the border -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Title" />

        <TextView
            style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Content here" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: This is an elegant solution! Thank you.

Comment: `fill_parent` was deprecated in android sdk 8, which was ages ago

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by putting two CardViews in a RelativeLayout. One with background of the border color and the other one with the image. (or whatever you wish to use)

Note the margin added to top and start for the second CardView. In my case I decided to use a 2dp thick border.

```
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/user_thumb_rounded_background"
            android:layout_width="36dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="18dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="6dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/user_thumb_background"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:layout_width="36dp"
                android:layout_height="36dp" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/user_thumb_rounded"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="6dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/user_thumb"
            android:src="@drawable/default_profile"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep `<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView`
with `android:foreground="@drawable/black_border"`

black_border :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/white" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@android:color/black" />
</shape>
```