# how to set colored border on cardview

Tags: android, material-design, android-appcompat, android-cardview

I am implementing card view but I can't find any border option to set a border on it.

here is my card.xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
  android:id="@+id/cardView"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
  app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
  xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

  <RelativeLayout
     android:background="@drawable/tab_bg"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:padding="16dp">

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/title"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Title"
         android:textSize="20sp" />

  </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

here is my image that I want to implement that green border on card view?

[image]

Help me. How can I implement this thing? I have no clue.

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add colored border on cardview?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35369691/how-to-add-colored-border-on-cardview)

Comment: That is not a cardview it is just a simple view with customize background made in drawable.xml, with border radius and border line

Comment: yes i 've seen but there is no solution of mine

Comment: I believe you are looking for a ShapeDrawable

Comment: he added one frame layout for left side border..  i want border around my cardview

Comment: Add  app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/md_lime_500" to your cardview.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Create drawable selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#808080"/>
    <stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="#B1BCBE" />
    <corners android:radius="20dp"/>
    <padding android:left="0dp" android:top="0dp"
             android:right="0dp" android:bottom="0dp" />
</shape>
```

then give set this as a background, change color according your choice

Comment: I did this but it doesn't apply to the card view and the background is still white color. any idea why is that happening?

Comment: android:background="@drawable/selector" Use this to add the shape

Answer (score 71):

Started from `v28` design support library we can use [Material Card View](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/card/MaterialCardView), which provides us with a material styled cardview implementation out of the box.

```
<android.support.design.card.MaterialCardView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">
    ... child views ...
</android.support.design.card.MaterialCardView>
```

You can further style the cardview by using two of the attributes that come with it:

- **app:strokeColor** - The colour to be used for the given stroke, this must be set in order to display a stroke
- **app:strokeWidth** - The width to be applied to the stroke of the view

Comment: This gives error. Use `android.support.design.card.MaterialCardView` by adding `    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'` in gradle

Comment: This response should be accepted. https://stackoverflow.com/users/5895830/sagar-chavada

Comment: @sagar-chavada This should be accepted answer as it not a workaround but actual implementation that material design library provides for material card view.

Comment: This is now deprecated. For new one follow the instructions on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57619574/android-x-design-dependency

Answer (score 34):

With the **material components library** just use the **`MaterialCardView`** with the **`app:strokeColor`** and **`app:strokeWidth`** attributes.

**Note** that without an `app:strokeColor`, the card will not render a stroked border, regardless of the `app:strokeWidth` value (the default values are `app:strokeColor=@null` and `app:strokeWidth=0dp`).

Something like:

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    ...
    app:strokeWidth="1dp"
    app:strokeColor="@color/stroke_color"
    app:cardElevation="xxdp">

    ...

</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

[image]

---

With **Jetpack Compose** you can use the **`border`** attribute in the **`Card`** composable:

```
Card( border= BorderStroke(1.dp, Red)){
    //.....
}
```

[image]

Comment: Should be the top rated answer, super simple solution without using any xml.

Answer (score 10):

here is the solution for your problem:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
   <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
   <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#00ff00"/>
   <corners android:radius="20dip"/>
</shape>
```

use it as background drawable of your layout

Comment: This simply doesn't work. I've applied it to my app and the result is just random

Answer (score 4):

I did this a little simpler by making the `cardBackgroundColor` green and `contentPadding` `1dp` and inside the card having a `ConstraintLayout` (or other layout) with a white background, like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorAccent"
        app:contentPadding="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:padding="8dp">

    ...
```

This way no extra xml or other superfluous code is needed.

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Though the question is very old, it may help others who face this problem. Just add the new MDC library in build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha05'
```

then in your layout add MaterialCardView

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    style="@style/CardViewStyle"
    app:strokeColor="@color/your_color"
    app:strokeWidth="@dimen/_1sdp">

</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

`in style.xml`

```
<style name="CardViewStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.CardView">
    <item name="cardBackgroundColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="cardForegroundColor">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="cardElevation">0dp</item>
    <item name="rippleColor">@color/colorRipple</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this by the following

1. CardItem for RecyclerView.

   > ```
   > <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView 
   >     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   >     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   >     xmlns:tool="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   >     android:layout_width="match_parent"
   >     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   >     android:layout_margin="@dimen/space"
   >     android:elevation="@dimen/space"
   >     app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/space">
   >
   >
   >     <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
   >         android:id="@+id/csl_language"
   >         android:layout_width="match_parent"
   >         android:layout_height="match_parent"
   >         android:background="@drawable/card_language_neutral"
   >         android:padding="@dimen/space">
   >        
   >         ..............        
   >
   >     </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
   > </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
   > ```
2. Note the @drawable/card_language_neutral as background in the child constraint layout

   card_language_neutral.xml

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
>
>     <stroke
>         android:width="1dp"
>         android:color="@color/black" />
>
>     <corners android:radius="@dimen/space" />
>
>     <padding
>         android:bottom="0dp"
>         android:left="0dp"
>         android:right="0dp"
>         android:top="0dp" />
>
> </shape>
> ```

[image]

3. Make sure that the `android:radius` attribute is set equal to the cardCornerRadius of CardView.  You can change the color, width of the border on the cardView using the background of child constraint layout, or relative layout in your case

[image]

NOTE: To programmatically change the background drawable to some other drawable (or some other color one) use the following

```
_csl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.card_language_glow)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my main file

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/tv_section"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:foreground="@drawable/bg_2_width"
            tools:foreground="@drawable/bg_2_width"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/pink_FF518A_light"
            app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/spacing_4"
            app:cardElevation="0dp"> 
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

`bg_2_width.xml` looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/pink_FF518A" />
    <corners android:radius="4dp" />
</shape>
```

and you can change the **width or color programmatically** from kotlin file

```
 val gradientDrawable = binding.tvSection.foreground as GradientDrawable
 gradientDrawable.setStroke(1, Color.Red) // place your desired color or border with
```