# RuntimeException when trying to shape corner of Cardview

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a CardView and I wanted to shape the corners of the cardview, I found a xml code snippet here and added it to my cardview and get this error, please look at the comment in the `test.xml` layout

**EDIT: When I change background of the cardview to "#ffffff" (white) it works. It only crashes when I use  card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@drawable/ic_corner_color"**

**EDIT 2: I want the corners look like this in the picture in the question, [click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36575069/how-to-set-colored-border-on-cardview)**

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.user.app/com.example.user.app.Test}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.CardView

This is my `test.xml` layout

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:tag="cards main container">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/card_viewtest"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@drawable/ic_corner_color" **// here is the error**
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
            card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
            card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:weightSum="1">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                        android:id="@+id/toolbar2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.96"
                        android:background="#ffffff"
                        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/imageViewtest"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_margin="5dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_drive_eta_black_24dp"
                            android:tag="image_tag" />

                    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textViewNametest"
                        android:layout_width="340dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

                        android:layout_weight="0.96"
                        android:text="some
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

My `ic_corner_color.xml`, which is in the drawable folder, looks like this:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
<solid android:color="#ffffff" />
<stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#00ff00"/>
<corners android:radius="20dip"/>
```

Comment: have u included compile `'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1'` ?? in gradle

Comment: you have to add dependency in your build.gradle file `com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1`

Comment: Please look at the edited question. It works, when I change background color to default color (white).

Comment: you can't add background to the cardView from the drawable folder

Comment: @IntelliJShivam ok, and how can I have a cardview like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36575069/how-to-set-colored-border-on-cardview ? This was my intention to have corners like this.

Comment: wait for my answer I have the solution..!! @Blnpwr

Comment: @IntelliJShivam ok, I am waiting.

Comment: check my answer @Blnpwr

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly sure `cardBackgroundColor` expects a color, not a drawable. Change it to `@color/mycolor`.

Comment: But then, I cannot add my shaped corners to my cardview?

Comment: Your cardview already has rounded corners with `card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"`

Comment: Ah, I understand but I want it like this picture in the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36575069/how-to-set-colored-border-on-cardview

Comment: just set the background then like this:         `android:background="@drawable/whatever"`

Comment: Because #ffffff is white? Try a different colour.

Comment: It does not change either. It is not only one color, it is going from white to green if you look at the xml code.

Comment: Green is the stroke (i.e. the outline). The white is the background colour.

Comment: Yes, and the stroke color does not work, i can't see anything in green.