# Set cardview border programmatically

Tags: android, android-cardview

Is there a way to set `CardView border` **programmatically**, I have a situation in which a hex code comes from API call and I need to draw the border of a cardview using that hex color.

I am not able to figure out, since I don't see any method to directly set the border of a cardView. I can only see the method to set the `backgroundColor`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36575069/how-to-set-colored-border-on-cardview/36575234

Comment: @DhruviShah .. read the question carefully, I am asking programatically not by using xml.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply wrap your layout into a `FrameLayout` with a small padding say, `3dp` and the desired border color as background color.