# android x design dependency

Tags: android, dependencies, androidx

How can I import androidx design dependency

I have tried to import : `implementation 'androidx.design:design:1.0.2'`

app compact version is : `implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'`

I have got this error -

> ERROR: Failed to resolve: androidx.design:design:1.0.2

Comment: use `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'`

Comment: Great it works! Thank you

Answer (score 53, accepted):

try this:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```

Answer (score 7):

To know equivalent for new Androidx Artifacts from old build artifacts, please refer the below link

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/artifact-mappings

**note**: answer by Poyyamozhi Ramakrishnan is correct and I posted my answer for better understanding.

Answer (score 3):

`implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha02'`

Just copy paste this one in to your dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

There is no design library in androidx. It uses material library. Get more info at 
[this](https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started/)

Answer (score 0):

`implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha06'`

Try this latest dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `'com.google.android.material:material-rc01'`