# How can I set border to my cardview?

Tags: android, android-layout

This is the below cardview code.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cv"
    android:background="@drawable/cardborder"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp">
```

below is cardborder.xml which I am using as background of cardview

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
    <stroke android:width="1dip"
        android:color="#f1efec"/>
    <corners android:radius="20dip"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: Increase the <stroke width you can see the border around your cardview.

Comment: I increased it upto 5 still unable to see any border

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46467680/1594998)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add colored border on cardview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35369691/how-to-add-colored-border-on-cardview)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to add another layout inside a card view and then set the background for that layout.
For card_view you can only set background color.

Comment: But I dont want that inner layout and cardview look seperated.

Answer (score 10):

I suggest another solution.

My cardviewItem:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/cardView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="7dp"
card_view:cardElevation="1dp">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/cardview_body">

        <TextView *** />

        <CheckBox *** />

        <ImageView *** />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And cardview_body.xml from drawable:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <layer-list>
        <item>
            <shape>
                <solid android:color="@color/DarkGrey"/>
                <corners android:radius="6dp" />
                <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@android:color/black" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
</item>
```

Important is the fact that the radius in cardview_body.xml is smaller than the radius in cardviewItem. Thanks to this, there is no spare white space at the corners.

Answer (score 7):

here is the solution for your problem

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <solid android:color="#808080"/>
  <stroke android:width="3dip" android:color="#B1BCBE" />
  <corners android:radius="20dip"/>
  <padding android:left="0dip" android:top="0dip" android:right="0dip" android:bottom="0dip" />
</shape>
```

hope it'll help you

Answer (score 3):

None of the Above answers worked for me . My solution is
Use a card inside a card with outer card with the border color . Keep the cornerRadius param same for both the cards:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
card_view:cardBackgroundColor="*Your Color*"
android:id="@+id/card_view"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
card_view:contentPadding="1dp"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<---- Here goes your Layout---------->

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

This creates a card with black border

Comment: This is not a good solution, this adds a redundant object to memory which will be a performance penalty.

Comment: you add redundant element in layout

Answer (score -1):

Or you can just use View to draw a border as below which is a 
long method but would create a exact border as it should look

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardMaxElevation="0.1dp"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@drawable/border_background"
    card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
    android:foreground="? 
    android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp_2"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dp_2"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_2"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dp_5">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_1"
        android:background="@color/Parrot_Color"
        android:id="@+id/view_topBorder"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="@dimen/dp_1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/Parrot_Color"
        android:id="@+id/Parrot_Color"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_1"
        android:background="@color/Parrot_Color"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="@dimen/dp_1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/Parrot_Color"
        android:layout_gravity="right"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

**I have created border around CardView**

hope it will solve your problem and help you

see the code and this card can be included into any Layout and then again we can set
Its layout_width and layout_height

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/euro"
    android:layout_height="20dp">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="58dp"
        android:layout_height="18dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp">



    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

[image]