# CardView Radius and Drawable Shape Radius are not same

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-cardview, material-components-android, cardview

I have below layout that has a `CardView`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:padding="50dp"
    >
  <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="200dp"
      app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/holo_red_light"
      app:cardCornerRadius="50dp"
      app:cardElevation="0dp"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
      >
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/outline"
        />
  </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And my `@drawable/outline` is just a stroke with corner radius same as `cardCornerRadius`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <corners android:radius="50dp" />
  <stroke
      android:width="3dp"
      android:color="@color/white" />
</shape>
```

So, I was expecting a `CardView` that has an outline. But this is what I get

[image]

Why does the radius of my stoke and radius of CardView are not the same and how to fix it?

Comment: I don't see a point of using a CardView if `cardElevation` is 0 .. It will show like a normal Layout ..

Comment: @ADM Whether cardElevation is 0 or not, the problem I have mentioned still occurs. I set cardElevation to 0 just to focus on the actual problem so that the problem is well shown

Comment: This can be resolve by adding some attributes to cardView maybe `app:cardUseCompatPadding` will work .. but my point is you can replace cardview with a normal layout if there is no elevation .. which is easy and effective ..

Comment: @ADM I see your concern. You can assume that I have cardElevation 10dp. `app:cardUseCompatPadding` that you have mentioned has no effect on the issue.

Comment: I think you can use [MaterialcardView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54921926/4168607).

Comment: @ADM Yes, sure I can. But I want to stick with CardView and fix this issue if it is fixable or if it is some kind of bug, then I can move and find different methods

Comment: @ADM the MaterialCardView with a stroke doesn't solve the issue. Check the detail in my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Check this issue](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/881#issuecomment-571771871) on `MaterialCardView` (but it is the same with the `androidx.cardview.widget.CardView`)

> It is due to Anti aliasing. **The background and the stroke are drawn on  the same pixels** but depending on the color of the stroke the transparent pixels added by the AA can cause the bleed through. That's why you won't see it if you invert the colors here.

You can achieve the same view just using

```
   <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/...."
        app:strokeWidth="3dp"
        app:strokeColor="@color/white />
```

[image]

As you can see:

[image]

You have another option.
You can apply the same `ShapeAppearanceModel` (**provided by default** by the `MaterialCardView`) to a simple `View` (or `Layout`) **inverting the colors** and **applying the margin** to the inner view.

```
   <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/corner_radius_16"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white">

        <View
            android:layout_margin="3dp"   
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/view_rounded"/>

    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

And then:

```
float size = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.cutout_size);

View viewRounded = findViewById(R.id.view_rounded);
ShapeAppearanceModel shapeAppearanceModelView = new ShapeAppearanceModel()
        .toBuilder()
        .setAllCorners(CornerFamily.ROUNDED,radius16)
        .build();
MaterialShapeDrawable shapeDrawableView = new MaterialShapeDrawable(shapeAppearanceModelView);
shapeDrawableView.setFillColor(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(this,R.color.xxx));
ViewCompat.setBackground(viewRounded,shapeDrawableView);
```

[image]

[image]